# Привязка текста ТекстБлока внутри шаблона колонки ДатаГрида к полю объекта второго уровня

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, wpf-шаблоны

У меня есть элемент dataGrid (Имя Dgrv) с колонками, определёнными при помощи тэга DataGridTemplateColumn. Вот код колонки, в которой у меня проблемы.

---

### XAML

---

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="40">
    <!--="Name"-->
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextCell.txtbx}" 
                           TextAlignment="Center" Margin="0, 8, 0, 0"/>
                <Canvas Background="Black" Height="1" Margin="5,5,5,0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding OperatorCode}" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="0, 5, 0, 0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Соответственно, заполнение в коде выглядит так:

---

### XAML.cs

---

```
var list = new List<Contract>();
list.Add(new Contract
{
    ID = 1,
    CompanyName = "Технабсервис",
    HeadName = "Петров\nАлександр\nНиколаевич",
    CountryCode = "+7",
    OperatorCode = "495",
    Date = Convert.ToDateTime("21.02.2012").ToString("dd.MM"), //GetDateTimeFormats('mm, dd'), 
    Time = "16:39",
    Telephones = "(495)123-4567 (общий)",
    Comment = ""
});
Dgrv.ItemsSource = list;
```

Вот мой класс Contract.cs, объекты которого я передаю в ДатаГрид

---

### Conract.cs

---

```
public class Contract
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string HeadName { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public string OperatorCode { get; set; }
    public String Date { get; set; }
    public String Time { get; set; }
    public String Telephones { get; set; }
    public String Comment { get; set; }
    public TextCell smth { get; set; }

    /*public Dictionary<string, int> PriceFields { get; private set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> RateFields { get; private set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> TypeFields { get; private set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> TicketFields { get; private set; }*/

    public Contract()
    {
        smth = new TextCell();
    }
}
```

И, наконец, сам класс TextCell, поле txtbx которого я хочу прибиндить к тексту текстБлока в колонке датаГрида

---

### TextCell.cs

---

```
public class TextCell
{
    public String txtbx { get; set; }
    public TextCell()
    {
        txtbx = "sdbjshfk";
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return txtbx;
    }
}
```

То есть вопрос касается вот этой части кода:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding TextCell.txtbx}" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="0, 8, 0, 0"/>
```

Она нерабочая. Я понимаю, что я могу прибиндить текст текстБлока к полю TextCell напрямую. В таком случае будет вызван метод ТуСтринг(), который я могу переопределить в классе и там выдать эту строку, но это, скорее хак для частного случая, а мне этого, к сожалению, недостаточно. В основном, это потому что ситуация, описанная в этом коде, это просто пример и в дальнейшей моей работе у меня встречается еще множество аналогичных ситуаций, но в них у меня не получится использовать данный хак и нужно что-то вроде того, что я кинул в нерабочем примере.

В общем, прошу не обращать внимания на незамысловатость класса TextCell.cs. Он был создан лишь для наглядности.

Comment: а так `<TextBlock Text="{Binding smth.txtbx}"`... работает?

Comment: _"Как здесь пометить как ответ"_ -- добавил как ответ. его можно отметить принятым.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В привязке надо указать имена свойств

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding smth.txtbx}" />
```

---

Синтаксис Binding.Path и примеры привязок [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms752300(v=vs.100).aspx#Path_Syntax).